# How do you shrink a UIPickerView on the iPhone?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uipickerview, picker

I would like to reduce the height of a `UIPickerView` in my iPhone app, so that it shows only one row and one column.  The height of the picker view should be equal to the height of a row.

I'm using Interface Builder to construct the `UIPickerView`, but I can't find an easy way to re-size this control.

How do you shrink a `UIPickerView`?

Comment: Try a UIScrollView and in the didScroll: method of the delegate do the snapping if the scrolling speed drops below a threshold.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Actually, you can slightly shrink the whole UIPickerView by applying an affine transform to an enclosing view.  For example:

```
CGSize pickerSize = [pickerView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];

pickerTransformView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, pickerSize.width, pickerSize.height)];
pickerTransformView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.75f, 0.75f);

[pickerTransformView addSubview:pickerView];
[self.view addSubview:pickerTransformView];
[pickerTransformView release];
```

will scale a picker to 75% of its original size by placing it within a containing view and applying a scaling transform to that view.  Applying a transform directly to the UIPickerView leads to undesirable drawing artifacts.

However, the kind of resizing you're looking for would be best served by creating a custom control.

Comment: +1 I've *never* thought of applying the transform to the superview!  I've always tried to apply it to the pickerview with unsatisfactory results.  I'd upvote this 10 times if I could.

Comment: I'm losing the ability to send touch events to the PickerView after rotating it. Thoughts?

Comment: @mark - Are you sure that the picker and its surrounding view are still within the bounds of their containing view?  If they are outside of the superview, touch events won't reach them.

Comment: Got it all sorted out - some connections in IB were not right. Thanks Brad - YOU ROCK!

Comment: how would we deal with its font size being messed up after scaling to 0.50f?

Comment: Would this kind of transform on a `UIPickerView` be acceptable by Apple?

Comment: I'm curious as to why directly scaling the picker would cause drawing artefacts, and scaling it indirectly via a subview won't

Comment: @rounak - The difference is between setting the frame for the view, which tells it to render at a given size, vs. having it render at a normal size, then applying a transform to that rendered content. The transform does a proportional scaling of the rasterized final version of the control, where the control doesn't know how to properly render all of its components at certain sizes.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible and easy!

Just open the nib file as plain text, then find the picker view and adjust the measures:

```
<object class="IBUIPickerView" id="783900772">
<reference key="NSNextResponder" ref="191373211"/>
<int key="NSvFlags">292</int>
<string key="NSFrame">{{85, 68}, {150, 116}}</string>
```

That's all!

Comment: When I add the bold text you write here, nothing happens. 
So I modified the next item-->NSFrameSize to {320, 116} (originally 320, 216). And this works.

Comment: I recommend setting "NSFrameSize" to {320, 130} as this will show the top 3 lines including picker's indicator. But the side effict is that  this will not show bottom frame of picker and users can't see anything other than the top 3 lines.

Comment: This is not changing anything for me.

Comment: doesn't work for me...this method change height only in interface xib but at runtime the pickerview remains same ...:-(

Answer (score 2):

The answer of user2248258 actually works if you use storyboards and/or autolayout. There I would like to add screenshots as Nilambar suggested.

1. place a pickerview in another container view with the size you want it [image: Place a pickerview into another container view]
2. check clipSubviews for the container view [image]
3. align the picker centered horizontally and vertically in that container view, also give it zero constraints for the trailing and leading place [image]

This way the picker view gets clipped off to the correct size (won't be resized).

Result:
[image]

Comment: This is a great suggestion, fits well to what I looked or.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it will be messed up if you shrink it.

a) `UITableView+UIPickerView`
I recommend you use the "a row in `UITableView+UIPickerView` to do this. You can use a row in tableView like the dropDownList in Windows, when you tap on this row will show the pickerView (hidden at first).

b)
If you have a long lists of data in tableView and only one of the items needs to pick data, you should scroll the view using the following method (make sure to calculate the original position of pickerView as it will be moved up/down together):

```
-(void)setViewMove:(BOOL)moveUP offset:(CGFloat)offset
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    CGRect rect = self.view.frame;

    if(moveUP)
    {
        rect.origin.y-=offset;
        rect.size.height+=offset;
    }
    else    //move down
    {
        rect.origin.y+=offset;
        rect.size.height-=offset;
    }
    self.view.frame = rect;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

c)
You can also add another view for the picker and go back to this view when you have selected something.

My conclusion is:
If you have only few lines in tableView, use a.
If you have lots of lines in tableView but only one of them needs picker, use b.
If you have lots of lines in tableView and lots of them need picker, use c.

Comment: is there a way we can create a drop down selector like we see in web pages

Comment: In web pages, the drop down list was originally created by other tools on Windows platform. Safari adds a unique control in order to see the dropDownList, but Apple doesn't add it to xcode.

Answer (score 1):

Create a simple UIView in Interface Builder. Set desired position and size, add constraints. Check "Clip SubViews" checkbox. Then drag & drop Picker View inside this view as a subview. Add constraints for picker to align horizontally and vertically inside container. Should do the job.

Comment: Some example with explanation would be great.

Comment: Unfortunately "reputation" of my Stackoverflow account  does not allow me to upload the images. I can mail you details if you would like.