# Change the Default Height of PickerControl

Tags: iphone

I want to increase of decrease the default height of UIPickerControl in iPhone Application.

May i know how to do this ?

Comment: This is a duplicate of the following questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905969/how-to-shrink-picker-view-in-iphone , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573979/how-to-change-uipickerview-height

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change the height of the Picker.  If you really need this you will have to create your own picker.

Comment: Actually, you can.  See the answers in the linked questions within my comment above.