# Two Resized Pickers. One loses touch input

Tags: iphone, resize, touch, uipickerview

For the accepted solution on this thread:
[How do you shrink a UIPickerView on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905969/how-do-you-shrink-a-uipickerview-on-the-iphone)

I can successfully re-size the picker. However I have TWO pickers in my controller. When I carry out the exercise for both pickers, they are re-sized, but when adding the transformed UIView to the main view, one of the transformed sub-views loses touch input. It's always the sub-view that is added FIRST that loses the touch input. how can i fix this?

Here is the code:

```
CGSize providerPickerSize = [providerPickerOutlet sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
CGSize amountPickerSize = [amountPickerOutlet sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];

UIView *providerPickerTransformView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, providerPickerSize.width, providerPickerSize.height)];
UIView *amountPickerTransformView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, amountPickerSize.width, amountPickerSize.height)];

providerPickerTransformView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.75f, 0.75f);
amountPickerTransformView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.75f, 0.75f);

[providerPickerTransformView addSubview:providerPickerOutlet];
[amountPickerTransformView addSubview:amountPickerOutlet];

[self.view addSubview:amountPickerTransformView];
[self.view addSubview:providerPickerTransformView];
```

Here the amountPickerTransformView loses touch input.

Using XCode 4.3, iOS 5 with storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Reason of losing touch on first added view is,

You are having two views of same frame one is `providerPickerTransformView` and other one is `amountPickerTransformView`.

now amountPickerTransformView is below the view `providerPickerTransformView`. so picker which add on `amountPickerTransformView` not taking the touch.

You need adjust frame of each view which contains picker appropriatley.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the x and y for the second view ie the view you want to the left side of the first view. As below

```
UIView *providerPickerTransformView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, providerPickerSize.width, providerPickerSize.height)];
UIView *amountPickerTransformView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(providerPickerSize.width, 0.0f, amountPickerSize.width, amountPickerSize.height)];
```

Happy Coding :)

**EDIT 1**

The problem as I can find in your code is

```
CGSize providerPickerSize = [providerPickerOutlet sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
CGSize amountPickerSize = [amountPickerOutlet sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
```

Replace `CGSizeZero` in those two lines with

```
CGSizeMake(CGFloat width, CGFloat height)
```

This will definitely solve your problem.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: The thing is, I'm using storyboard to put in the pickers. To re-size the pickers I have to put the full size picker on the storyboard in a funny position, for the re-sized picker to show in the proper place. Now when I implement your solution, or try to give the amountPickerTransformView any x coordinate other than 0.0f, it disappears completely. very confusing.

Comment: Have you tried to hard code the width in this code like in place of amountPickerSize.width put some hard coded value like 250 or what you want :)?

Comment: Yes, for smaller values like 10.0 or 20.0 it is visible(sans touch), but for greater hard-coded values it disappears.

Comment: ok have to look at it and practically have to made one example for it and will post you the exact code for it :)

Comment: Tell me that `providerPickerOutlet` and `amountPickerOutlet` what are these? Which type of iVar? :)

Comment: Hi get the whole code from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/s05zg3mxll7n1h1/kvIWrPs2iQ)