# Is it possible to 're-skin' the IOS Date Picker?

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface

I require a custom date picker, essentially just want to remove the graphics in the IOS version but retain the 3 column date scroll. Does it need to be re-built from scratch (all research points to yes) , or is it possible to just disable or swap the images.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it myself, but maybe you could just add a UIImageView above the datepicker with a transparent section for the scrolling sections to show through.

Comment: I thought about that, however our UI is very minimal, we want to get rid of the gloss and other surrounding graphics. Keep it within our minimal style.

Answer (score 0):

[Change UIPickerView background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965375/change-uipickerview-background) check adam's answer there relating to picker views.

I have altered those before for a picker, so the datepicker might be similar.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change the images of a UIDatePicker.  UIPickerView you can, but as you say, you would lose a lot of functionality.