# UIPickerView remove gradient borders

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

How can i remove gradient borders arround UIPickerView?

And, if possible, change color of selection from blue to grey.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no easy way to do it unfortuantely. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965375/change-uipickerview-background) for some suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

I have placed the uipicker within a smaller uiview with the clip bounds property set on the picker.