# Change the Backgroundcolor of a UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uipickerview, background-color

I want to change the Color of the "Barrel" inside the picker with a gradient from red to blue (Temperature: hot to cold).

I could draw the gradient piece by piece with `-(UIView*)pickerView:(UIPickerView*)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView*)view`

but then, what's about the space over the first and under the last row?

Is there a better way to do this? Or is it possible to manipulate the "Barrel" directly?

Comment: Please Refer "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965375/change-uipickerview-background"