# Theme the IOS UI Picker using Monotouch

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios

I have a monotouch project and I am trying to theme the uipicker without any luck. I have tried setting backgroundcolors to clear however none seem to do much.

To start with I don't want to do anything to difficult I really just want to be able to clear the black background then remove the 2 tone gradient bar that the picker is inside.

Any monotouch gurus care to lend a hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not an easy task (Apple doesn't have a clear cut way to do this). Read some of the options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965375/change-uipickerview-background).

So you can either:

- Create an image with a transparent center to add a `UIImageView` as a subview,
- Try settings properties on a `Subview` of `UIPickerView`
- Try porting their [IXPickerOverlayView](https://github.com/Inexika/Inexika-Custom-Controls/tree/master/IXPickerOverlayView) to MonoTouch