# How to change the height of a UIPickerView on ios 4.3?

Tags: height, uipickerview, ios4

Hi i would like to know if its at all possible to change the height of a UIPickerView on IPhone IOS 4.3.

Creating the UIPickerView programmatically doesn't work

Setting the frame size programmatically doesn't work

Modifying the source code of the xib file doesn't work (Does on ipad)

Cheers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573979/how-to-change-uipickerview-height