# Make more than 5 lines viewable on UIPickerView

Tags: ios4, ipad, uipickerview, uipicker

The default UIPickerView shows the current selection along with two options above and two options below the current section.

Is there a way to adjust this show that it shows more lines at a given time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height of UIPickerView is fixed and cannot be adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to a similar question with answers on how to change the height though there are only a few allowed heights for the `UIPickerView`. [How to change UIPickerView height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573979/how-to-change-uipickerview-height/9674444#9674444)