# How to change the dimensions of picker view?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uipickerview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to decrease the height of the Uipickerview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105940/how-to-decrease-the-height-of-the-uipickerview)

In my application I want to change the height of the picker view. Please give me any information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `.frame` property and set the `CGRect`.

```
[picker setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 120, 320, 215) ];

CGRectMake ( x, y, width, height)
```

Comment: Ok sir,We can do that one sir.Just now i find that one sir.Right click on .xib open as XML.And find <object class="IBUIPickerView"...And in that we contain <string key="NSFrame">{{-9, 244}, {338, 216}}</string>.So change the 244 and 216.