# Change number of displayed rows in UIPickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6, uipickerview

Is there a way to change the number of displayed rows in a `UIPickerView` from 5 to 4?  The height of the picker doesn't seem to be adjustable in IB and i can't find any delegate methods to control this.

Please note that I'm asking about the number of displayed rows, not the number of rows in the component.

Comment: you want to select another row programmatically am I right?

Comment: no, i am trying to show 4 rows instead of 5 in the uipickerview.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the height of the rows in a `UIPickerview` using the following `UIPickerViewDelegate` method

```
- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView rowHeightForComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
  return 60.0f;
}
```

I'm not sure of the exact height you'd need to get four rows displaying.  Might just have to fiddle with that until you get it right!

Comment: thanks! the issue that i'm having is i'm trying to design to a comp using images as the rows. i'm using this method already to match the height of the images. the issue is that i'm trying to reduce the vertical height of the entire picker component so that i'm showing 4 rows with each row at the specified height.

Answer (score 0):

There is not direct way given by Apple, which allows us to change `UIPickerView` height using `setFrame`.

But there are two way-arounds to achive the same:

- First in nib file code (XML format), you can change tag values according to requirement. Here is the reference: [How to decrease the height of the Uipickerview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105940/how-to-decrease-the-height-of-the-uipickerview)
- The other way is to change height-width using core-animation properties (Scale & Translate). For your requirement I guess this would be helpful to you. Here is the reference: [UIPickerView Height not changeable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12473566/uipickerview-height-not-changeable)

Hope this will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot mess up alot with uipickerview height, reason being once you change the height you have to readjust each of the row size and the font for each of the row so that they are displayed clearly and separately. There are only three valid heights for UiPickerview (162.0, 180.0 and 216.0). However you can change the height by the following

```
CGAffineTransform t0 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation (0, mypickview.bounds.size.height/2);
CGAffineTransform s0 = CGAffineTransformMakeScale       (1.0, 0.5);
CGAffineTransform t1 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation (0, -mypickview.bounds.size.height/2);
mypickview.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat          (t0, CGAffineTransformConcat(s0, t1));
```

Comment: thanks, i'll try this out and see if these heights correspond to a number of displayed rows.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to set height of the `UIPickerView` then you can use :

```
picketView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 0.70);
```

Above code will scale the `UIPickerView`.

Comment: But this won't change the number of displayed rows since the rows will be transformed as well.

Comment: I have given answer for adjust height of UIPIckerView.

Comment: The primary question is `Is there a way to change the number of displayed rows in a UIPickerView from 5 to 4?`

Comment: But secondary question is also for adjust height of the UIPickerView.