# UIPickerView Height not changeable

Tags: iphone, ios, frame, uipickerview

I'm trying to change PickerView's height

```
self.pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
self.pickerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
```

Xcode log shows the following message:

```
-[UIPickerView setFrame:]: invalid height value 274.0 pinned to 216.0
```

How can I change its height?

Comment: you can not change height of UIPickerView.

Comment: On iOS 9 everything has changed! http://stackoverflow.com/a/35562894/8047

Answer (score 30, accepted):

here are only `three` `valid` `heights` for `UIPickerView` `(162.0, 180.0 and 216.0)`.

You can use the `CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation` and `CGAffineTransformMakeScale` functions to properly fit the picker to your convenience.

Example:

```
CGAffineTransform t0 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation (0, pickerview.bounds.size.height/2);
CGAffineTransform s0 = CGAffineTransformMakeScale       (1.0, 0.5);
CGAffineTransform t1 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation (0, -pickerview.bounds.size.height/2);
pickerview.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat          (t0, CGAffineTransformConcat(s0, t1));
```

The above code `change` the `height` of `picker` `view to half` and `re-position` it to the exact `(Left-x1, Top-y1)` position.

Refer more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573979/how-to-change-uipickerview-height?rq=1).

Answer (score 3):

There are only three valid heights for `UIPickerView (162.0, 180.0 and 216.0)`.

[More detail.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7672577/616094)

Answer (score 1):

There are only three valid values 162.0, 180.0 and 216.0 for height of the UIPicker. even if you set different height it will set the height to the one of the these three heights which is nearest to your given height.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. I also googled so many examples and found this one.

```
pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,250,320,230)];//to change the height
pickerView.delegate =self;
pickerView.dataSource =self;
pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
[self.view addSubview:pickerView];
```