# UIPickerview filling the screen

Tags: ios, height, width, picker

I want an UIPickerView that fills all the screen. This is the code i have ...

```
pickerView1 = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
[pickerView1 setDelegate: self];
[pickerView1 setFrame: CGRectMake(0,0, 480, 320)];
[self.view addSubview: pickerView1];
```

This just fills the width, not the height, and I get this message in the output:
" invalid height value 320.0 pinned to 216.0  "

Why ? How can i adjust the height of the picker ???

Answer (score 1):

You just can't adjust the height of a UIPickerView. Check this topic for more information : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573979/how-to-change-uipickerview-height)

However, you can change the width.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can increase the height of a picker view beyond a certain point.(not sure what that is though, but its around 240 max) Not sure if its because of the example, but your W and H are inverted, so your picker goes off the screen because of that.

```
UIPickerView *pickerView1 = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 240.0)];
```