# Xcode 5 Picker Height

Tags: xcode, ios7, uipicker

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573979/how-to-change-uipickerview-height) there are only 3 accepted heights for the picker

> There are only three valid heights for UIPickerView (162.0, 180.0 and
>   216.0).
>
> You can use the CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation and
>   CGAffineTransformMakeScale functions to properly fit the picker to
>   your convenience.
>
> Example:
>
> CGAffineTransform t0 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation (0,
>   pickerview.bounds.size.height/2); CGAffineTransform s0 =
>   CGAffineTransformMakeScale       (1.0, 0.5); CGAffineTransform t1 =
>   CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation (0,
>   -pickerview.bounds.size.height/2); pickerview.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat          (t0, CGAffineTransformConcat(s0,
>   t1));

How do I use this code to set the height to 216.0 and set it at the bottom of the iPhone 5 screen?

Thankyou.