# How to customise UIPickerView height?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, customization, uipickerview

How can I customise the height of a UIPickerView? I would like it to be taller more than 250.

I have done the following but I'm unable to set the given height.

```
-(void)pickerview:(id)sender
{
    pickerView=[[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,200,320,400)];
    pickerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.75f, 0.75f);
    pickerView.delegate = self;
    pickerView.dataSource = self;
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    pickerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [pickerView selectRow:1 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:pickerView];
    // [contentView addSubview:pickerView];
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Here there are only three valid heights for UIPickerView (162.0, 180.0 and 216.0).

You can use the **CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation** and **CGAffineTransformMakeScale** functions to properly fit the picker to your convenience.

Example:

```
CGAffineTransform t0 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation( 0,
    pickerview.bounds.size.height/2 );
CGAffineTransform s0 = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 0.5);
CGAffineTransform t1 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation( 0,
    pickerview.bounds.size.height/-2 );
pickerview.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat( t0,
    CGAffineTransformConcat(s0, t1) );
```

The above code change the height of picker view to half and re-position it to the exact (Left-x1, Top-y1) position.

Refer more here.
[How to change UIPickerView height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573979/how-to-change-uipickerview-height?rq=1)