# How can you increase the standard UIPickerView Swift.

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

How can you increase the standard UIPickerView. 
In standart UIPickerView have 5 visible rows only.
Needed PickerView with size in full screen.

Can anyone help with this problem?

Needed PickerView as in the picture

https://i.stack.imgur.com/olPnH.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible now because:

The pickerView's height is no longer re-sizable. There is a message which gets dumped to console if you attempt to change the frame of a picker.

```
[UIPickerView setFrame:]: invalid height value 400.0 pinned to 216.0
```

There are only three valid heights for `UIPickerView` which is 162.0, 180.0 and 216.0.

For more Info refer [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573979/how-to-change-uipickerview-height) question.

But you can use custom picker view like [THIS](https://github.com/roofeel/DDMultiPickerView).

Answer (score 2):

it's possible oO

swift

```
datePickerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 340)
```

[image]