# Remove the gap above and below UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker, inputview

Looking to remove the default gap between the date text and the top of my input view. Is there a way to make the picker frame bigger than the input view?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change UIPickerView height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573979/how-to-change-uipickerview-height)

Comment: You can change the UIPickerView height but that changes the inputview height. I'm hoping to clip the UIPickerView.